# How to setup two loops that extract excel files from a page with Imacros

Tags: loops, scripting, extract, imacros

Hi I'm kind of new to this kind of coding so u would like to have some feedback on how to make this work.

I'm trying to setup two loops.
I want to be able to like type a citys name and be able to see all the companys that's located in the the city I search for and then make it go in and download a file about this company in cvs format. .

I'm thankfull for all feedback and I'm willing to reward the person who can solve my big problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";

for(var i=1; i<10;i++)
{
for(var j=1; j<10;j++)
{

iimPlay(macro)


}

}
```

This is example of iMacros JS Scripting with 2 loops. Tell us the rest and we will give you better code.

Comment: What more do you need? Do u have WebEx? I can show you what I mean.. I'm real bad with this kind of stuff..

Comment: I think i Have found a soultion on it.. But i got stuck on one thing.  If I'm for a exampel are on " www.facebook.com/exampleone" and I want it to change  only the in URL from " exampleone" to "exampletwo" and "examplethree" what kind of code do I need?

Comment: That needs a lot of JS. Start practicing on www.jsfiddle.net and use split(), replace() methods.